# Ajax Control Toolkit Filter Types

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've a radiobuttonlist and an textbox like this ;

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonFirm" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonFirm_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="Code - int" />
                            <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="Name - string" />
  </asp:RadioButtonList>



<asp:TextBox ID="txtCriteria" Width="120px" SkinID="TextBoxDefault" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtCriteria_FilteredTextBoxExtender" runat="server"
                                Enabled="True" FilterType="Numbers" TargetControlID="txtCriteria">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Code behind :

```
 protected void RadioButtonFirm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButtonFirm.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            txtCriteria_FilteredTextBoxExtender.FilterType = AjaxControlToolkit.FilterTypes.Numbers;            
        }
        else
        {           
            txtCriteria_FilteredTextBoxExtender.FilterType = AjaxControlToolkit.FilterTypes.Custom;
        }
    }
```

It's not working. If I changed radiobuttonlist, I still can enter string values. I want to enter integer or string to textbox according to radiobutton selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to set it dynamically.

```
TextBoxFilter.set_FilterType(2);
```

values for the types are

```
AjaxControlToolkit.FilterTypes.prototype = {
    Custom           :  0x1,      //1
    Numbers          :  0x2,     //2
    UppercaseLetters :  0x4,   //3
    LowercaseLetters :  0x8    //4
}
```